# jQuery fade in content while using Ajax .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to use something like jQuery `.fadeIn()` on a 'load more' button pulling JSON html markup from the server on `.append(response)`.  syntax like `.append(response).fadeIn('slow');` does not seem to work, I believe its a DOM issue because the data is appended to the page before `.fadeIn()` has a chance to work.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this type of effect?  my JavaScript is below.

```
$(function () {
var offset = 10;

$(".load-more-cell").click(function() {
    $.post("load-more-notifications", {offset: offset, limit: 30}, 
        function (response) {
        $(".notification-table-body").append(response);
        offset += 30;
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried fadeIn('slow', function() { ... change here hmlt ... } 0 ???

Comment: undefined's answer below worked like a charm for me.  Because append returns the current collection elements and not the appended elements any use of `.fadeIn()` would not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` returns the current collection, i.e. `".notification-table-body"` elements, it doesn't contain the appended elements, if you want to call the `fadeIn` on the appended elements you should at first create a collection that contains them and then call the method:

```
$(response).hide().appendTo('.notification-table-body').fadeIn();
```

Comment: I do not understand how this works only on the last elements, but it works :)